# Oracle SQL Query based on a UNION

Tags: sql, oracle, union, oracle12c

env: Oracle 12c

I have a query in Oracle that is a UNION between two tables: TABLE_A and TABLE_B.

```
select ID as COL_A,
       VAL_B as COL_B,
       VAL_C as COL_C,
       VAL_D as COL_D,
       VAL_E as COL_E
from   TABLE_A
where  VAL_E = 'XYZ12'
union
select NULL as COL_A,
       NULL_B as COL_B,
       VAL_C as  COL_C,
       NULL as COL_D,
       VAL_E as COL_E
from   TABLE_B
where  VAL_E = 'XYZ12'
and    ?????

COL_A  COL_B  COL_C  COL_D COL_E
------ ------ ------ ----- -----
123    REQ1   REQ2   REQ3  XYZ12
              REQ2         XYZ12
```

Based on the query above and where I am stuck is that if the record with `'XYZ12' and 'REQ1'` exists then I only want to return this one record otherwise return the second record only, i.e. where 'XYZ12' exists but `COL_B IS NULL`

The primary record is the first one if it exists in TABLE_A. Based on my criteria, if it doesn't exist then return the second record alone from TABLE_B.

Comment: Do your tables really only have one row?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: @GordonLinoff the record will either exist in TABLE_A or TABLE_B and the column of concern is COL_E, specifically 'XYZ12'. Each table has one row for 'XYZ12'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data and query in your question, `table_a` would seem to have at most one row.  Hence you can simply add:

```
from TABLE_B 
where VAL_E = 'XYZ12' and
      not exists (select 1 from table_a a)
```

If you want to check for specific values in `table_a`, then you can add a filter to the subquery.

Comment: I would only want to return table_A record if COL_E = 'XYZ12 and COL_B IS NOT NULL otherwise return record from TABLE_B.

Comment: @tonf . . . Add that condition to the subquery.